# Divergence, gradient, differential equation

Tags: differential-geometry

Got the following problem:
Solve the equation 2rdiv(grad(f(r)))=div(r/||r||), where r = r(x,y,z) and ||r|| is a norm of r.
As I see it, I need to simplify both sides and get a differential equation. I’m having trouble with div and grad, though. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Welcome! [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: You might start by writing the gradient and divergence in spherical coordinates and assume that $f$ is a function of $\|r\|$ only to start.